# Export Piazza groups

Tags: export, piazza

How can I export [Piazza groups](https://web.archive.org/web/20190828001126/https://support.piazza.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1563994-create-groups), i.e. get the list of all groups as well as the emails of their members?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116510/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-export-piazza-groups).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot export Piazza groups, i.e. get the list of all groups as well as the emails of their members, as a regular member of class. However it is possible to do so as an admin: go to the admin panel to export it.